# Best way for test Unix Domain Socket (like ab,wget or PostMan)

Tags: testing, benchmarking, unix-socket

I know UDS-protocol is faster(almost best for most-case) than TCP , but what are good testing(and benchmarking) program for UDS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try httpie with a plugin. See https://github.com/httpie/httpie-unixsocket